# elapsed time between the two loops

Tags: python, time, elapsedtime

I want to measure the time difference (inseconds) between two lines of code.

```
while ret:
    ret, image_np=cap.read()
    time_1
    for condition:
         if condition:
             time_2
```

I want to subtract `(time_2) - (time_1)`. But the problem is that `time_1` always changes and I can't calculate the time.

Comment: Please edit your code so that it can be run easily. Use consistent indentation and colons `(:)` after `for` and `if` to start with

Comment: What is exactly the issue ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could store the values directly in an array and change your time_1 value each time you append a value to the array. Here is what it could look like :

```
from datetime import datetime

time_1 = datetime.now()
elapsed_time = []

# In my example I loop from 0 to 9 and take the elapsed time
# when the value is 0 or 5
for i in range(10):
    if i in [0,5]:
        elapsed_time.append(datetime.now()-time_1)
        time_1 = datetime.now()
```